# Error 400 on SERVER: The environment must be purely alphanumeric, not 'puppet-ca'

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I would like to share this mistake as i have waste for one day on this.
So I think i might be useful for other

There is a puppet server setup by my colleague in infrastructure team.
They provide me another window 2008 r2 to install puppet agent on my own.

I try to run puppet agent and it always show message

> Error 400 on SERVER: The environment must be purely alphanumeric, not
>   'puppet-ca'

Comment: I want a feedback that why this question have been dowvoted so that i would consider improving the question.

Comment: Try running as sudo. I faced this error when trying to apply settings using --environment. Using sudo resolved the error. I know that's weird.

Comment: I'll second the comment about sudo. I ran the agent as non-root and got the same error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The root cause is that the puppet version on puppet master server is 3.8.1
However i install puppet 4.1.0 on puppet agent.

Puppet master version must be greater than or equal puppet agent version.
The solution is that i uninstall puppet on puppet agent and reinstall puppet version 3.8.1 instead.

You may find previous release downloads at the following link: https://puppet.com/misc/pe-files/previous-releases

Answer (score 0):

In my case this problem was caused by missing environment variable in puppet.conf. After running with --environment production all works as expected.